# angular.js cookies is not stored expire time and domain name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am new and trying to store cookies and parameter to expire cookies , domain name , secure etc.
I setup a factory to store cookies

```
app.factory('SetCookies',function($cookieStore,$timeout,$window){
 var authService = {};   
 authService.create = function (username,email,id,sessionID) {   
                        var expired = new Date();
                        expired.setTime(expired.getTime() + (10*1000));                                                 
                        $cookieStore.put('Name',username, {expires : expired, secure:true, domain:'http://localhost/test' });
                        $cookieStore.put('Email',email, {expires : expired, secure:true, domain:'http://localhost/test' });
                        $cookieStore.put('LogCode',id, {expires : expired, secure:true, domain:'http://localhost/test' });
                        $cookieStore.put('Token',sessionID, {expires : expired, secure:true, domain:'http://localhost/test' });
                        $cookieStore.put('isLoggedIn',true, {expires : expired, secure:true, domain:'http://localhost/test' });         

                        };
return authService;
```

})

i have called this to in my login controller to set cookies

```
SetCookies.create(user.data.username, user.data.email, user.data.id, user.data.session_id);
```

after login i have checked cookies timeout on main controller

```
$timeout(function(){
        if(!$cookieStore.get('isLoggedIn')){
                $location.path('/');
                }
    },20);
```

but when i have checked it on all browsers there are only value.

result is like below screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqO30.png)

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs cookiestore is deprecated. You should use [$cookies](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) instead. But I've found that it can have a bit bloat to it. In past I've always opted to just use native JavaScript when it comes to cookies.

Comment: after using $cookies instead of $cookieStore getting error in console 
"$cookies.get is not a function"

Comment: Have you included $cookies in both factory and controller?

Comment: factory 
app.factory('SetCookies',function($cookies,$cookieStore,$timeout,$window)
controller
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService, $theme, SetCookies)
main controller

Comment: Remove $cookieStore from your factory as this is no longer used. And add $cookies after SetCookies

Comment: $cookies.put is not a function
is it cookies version problem?
how to update version of cookies.

Comment: Sorry I think know problem. ngCookies module is needed as a dependency in your angular module. Refer to the documentation here. It gives you the link to the cdn. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies once that's in there and you have included both $cookies in factory and controller should work

Comment: i am using 
AngularJS v1.3.10

Comment: Ah that's why prior to v1.4 there were no getters and setters. What is reason for using old version? Is it possible for you to upgrade to greater than 1.4?

Comment: because it my client website or when i am upgrading angular site is not working 
now i have set cookies 
var expired = new Date();
           expired.setTime(expired.getTime() + (10*1000));
       $cookies.Name   = username;
       $cookies.Email   = email;

but how to set expire time in it can you advise me bcoz all working fine only i need set expire time or domain etc

Comment: To be honest as you're running such a old version it's probably not worth including another module and having that extra request on page. I would just native JavaScript where you can create and function to get and set your cookies. You can even add expiry date. Sorry to take you round in circles. If you need it here is the w3c article on js cookies http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @RedSymbol did this help you?

Comment: not but i find out solution. can you suggest me how to delete cookies if i close tab of browser and when i reopen it, i want to logout or destroy cookies?

Comment: if you dont set an expiry date in your cookie it will become a session cookie... if you want to do it on log out you would need to set an expiry date in the past this will then delete the cookie